# Как выбрать данные из SQLite в Unity, с помощью библиотеки SQLite4Unity3d?

Tags: c#, sql, unity3d, sqlite

Использую в Unity базу данных SQLite.

Мне посоветовали библиотеку SQLite4Unity3d.
Вот код библиотеки.

Ссылка ведет на строку 646 где описан метод Execute.
https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d/blob/master/Example/Assets/Scripts/SQLite.cs#L646

Этот метод выполняет INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. А также там написано

> Use this method instead of Query when you don't expect rows back.

То есть в коде должен быть метод, который выполняет выборку.
Не могли бы вы подсказать где этот метод (я не смог найти) и как выбрать данные (пример C# кода) моей БД?

PS
SQL запросы знаю, общий принцип понимаю.

Вот пример кода, работающего с этой библиотекой, для вставки данных в БД.

```
string dbPath = string.Format(@"Assets/StreamingAssets/{0}", "mybase.db");
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
string sqlQuery ="INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2) VALUES ('тест1', 'Test2')";
string sqlParams ="";
/// INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs.
int result = connection.Execute (sqlQuery, sqlParams); // Работает. Вставляет данные в БД.
```

Comment: Метод `Query` делает выборку. Там же в документации.

Comment: Зачем вам база на клиенте? Что в ней хранить, `PlayerPrefs`? :) А если это сервер, то почему SQLite?

Comment: Alexander Petrov - на какой строке? Можно пример кода на c#?
Я не работал с этой библиотекой.

aepot - SQLite стандартная БД для хранения данных приложения на клиенте.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d/blob/9b9d4fa1e3b16b1b02288b11898cce565a060b6c/Example/Assets/Scripts/SQLite.cs#L723)